# File path not accessible from Sitecore link manager

Tags: link-manager

Sitecore Version: 9.3 with SXA

We want to access the local file directory from the Link on the website. For that, we have entered, file directory path in *Insert External Link*.

[image]

After that, On the website, when we tried to click on the link, we are getting the error "*Not allowed to load local resource*":

[image]

But if we do the same thing in static HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample Code</title>
</head>
 <body>
    <h1>Opening a folder from HTML code</h1>
    <a href="c://">
        Click to open a folder
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

and click on the link, we are able to open the file directory.

Does anyone know the reason, why file paths are not accessible when the link is generated through the Sitecore link manager?

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's probably a no go for many reasons. What files are on the drive that cannot be uploaded into Sitecore?

Comment: This is an IntranetPortal and the client want to access a local drive from portal.

Comment: Consider making a web service that serves up the data to a custom component. Then the  web service application can run under a different service account (with access to the drive) and is then shielded from anyone directly calling it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @MichaelWest

Answer (score 2):

It is not related to Sitecore link manager, there are many reasons and with some security reasons, browsers do not allow to load local resources, and anyway, it will run on the client-side, not on the server-side, where users can use the windows explorer. For your static HTML part, I guess you are running it from your local, not as a website and that's is the reason it is working for you but when you will host it will not work for the static HTML as well.

As per your comment - "This is an IntranetPortal and the client want to access a local drive from the portal." - if you add `c://` in the link and somehow it works then also it will not complete your requirement because as I told you it will not run on the server-side and the end-user will see the local c drive of his, not the server where you hosted it.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, Mahendra. You're right, this is not truly related to Sitecore Link manager but applies to any link in general.